# how to listen global touch events even form isnt focused

Tags: c#, wpf

I found that

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
```

will be able to capture global touch event and does exactly what I'm looking for (return x,y and tell me if this is coming from touch not mouse). but! I want to get multiple touch events. `SetWindowsHookEx` gives me only one touch. When there are 3 touches moving on the screen, I want to be able to get all 3 touches and their coords.

I found these might help

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern bool RegisterRawInputDevices(RAWINPUTDEVICE[] pRawInputDevice, uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceList(IntPtr pRawInputDeviceList, ref uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize);
```

but i'm very new to c# and have no clue how to utilize those. I was getting 9 devices when called `GetRawInputDeviceList()` but not able to tell which one is the touchscreen. even if I do, I still don't know how to track all the touches. detailed example would be super appreciated.

Comment: if it can, then you(or somebody) can steal passwords?

Comment: it can. check out http://gesturesign.win

Comment: > "When there are 3 touches moving on the screen, I want to be able to get all 3 touches and their coords."
Do you mean 3 concurrent touches? (multi-touch)

Comment: @Cybrus yes, 3 concurrent touches

Comment: I have found several links that might be helpful:  
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562199(v=vs.85).aspx), [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668404/Programming-for-Multi-Touch)